# Getting all unique combinations from a list of lists up to the nth combination only

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list of lists where the variables in each of the inner lists is a path to an image. Usually each inner list will have a length of about 35 and there will be 9 of these lists within a list. e.g

```
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]
```

None

I want to generate unique combinations of 9, from this list list of list. If I use itertools.product it works, but takes much too long - it crashes my computer. What I need is something that will keep going up to the nth combination whereby n might be about 200. I've tried this...

```
  list(itertools.product(*z))[:200]
```

where z is my list of lists but it doesn't work because it generates all combos first before doing the slice (far too slow).

Is there any other efficient way to run this?

EDIT: I should add that I need to convert this to a list of lists...

Benchmarking:

Brad:

```
 def combos():
     my_iter = itertools.product(*z)
     print([next(my_iter) for i in range(1, 10000)]

cProfile.run('print(combos())')
     10006 function calls in 0.021 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.021 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.021 gcm.py:17(combos)
    1    0.002    0.002    0.004    0.004 gcm.py:19(<listcomp>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.021 {built-in method builtins.exec}
 9999    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method builtins.next}
    2    0.016    0.008    0.016    0.008 {built-in method builtins.print}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

DeepSpaces updated answer:

```
 cProfile.run('print(list(my_gen(z, 10000)))')

 10005 function calls in 0.019 seconds

 Ordered by: standard name

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.001    0.001    0.019    0.019 <string>:1(<module>)
10001    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 gcm.py:10(my_gen)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.019    0.019 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    1    0.014    0.014    0.014    0.014 {built-in method builtins.print}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

to get a step in this I did this...

```
   def my_gen(z, limit):
      count = 0
      for i in itertools.product(*z):
         if count < limit:
            if count % 1000 == 0:
               yield i
               count += 1
            else:
               count += 1
               continue
      else:
        raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Using the %timeit magic in IPython (and removing `print` functions), I get 1.57ms for `list(my_gen(z, 10000))` and 1.47ms for `combos()`.  I'm not sure why you have such a large difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting `itertools.product(*z)` to a list and slicing, wrap it with your own generator:

```
def my_gen(z, limit):
    count = 0
    for i in itertools.product(*z):
        if count < limit:
            yield i
            count += 1
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

**EDIT** Brad's answer shows a somehow similar idea but will still create a list with 200 elements in memory, while my approach won't (unless called within `list(...)`).

**EDIT 2**

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

print(list(my_gen(lists, 2)))
#  [(1, 6), (1, 7)]
print(list(my_gen(lists, 3)))
#  [(1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8)]
print(list(my_gen(lists, 4)))
#  [(1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9)]
```

Comment: This yields a generator quickly enough, but I need to convert that to a list which is the killer

Comment: @GhostRider You can convert it to list, ie `list(my_gen(..))`. It will only convert the results to a list (ie you will get a list with `n` products rather than all the products). If `n` itself is too large to fit in memory then there isn't really something you can do about it. See my updated answer.

Comment: @GhostRider The code in Brad's answer has the exact same behavior of the code in my answer if the function called within `list(...)`, so if `n` is too big you will have the exact same memory problem.

Comment: Why have go the benchmark results above - I am willing to be told I've made a mistake!

Comment: I think you should shortcircuit with StopIteration

Comment: @Adirio I used `break`, but indeed I think `StopIteration` is the better option.

Comment: @GhostRider Please note that I've edited the code in the answer.

Comment: @DeepSpace, would there be a straightfoward way to yield the results in steps i.e get the first 200 at steps of 10, or 20....

Comment: @GhostRider Not quite, but perhaps you can mess around with the `if count < limit` condition.

Comment: @Adirio and @DeepSpace, I don't think `StopIteration` is the preferred method any longer.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/  Maybe I misunderstand, but I believe generators should simply return when they are done.

Comment: Yes, if aiming at Python 3.5+ swap `raise StopIteration` by `return`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
my_iter = itertools.product(*z)
[next(my_iter) for i in range(200)]
```

Comment: This is correct, just keep in mind this will still create a list with 200 elements in memory. It can be fixed by changing the `[...]` to `(...)`.

Comment: Is there any to add a step to this i.e. instead of next, go in steps of say, 20?

Comment: If you do this `[next(my_iter) for i in range(20)]`, `my_iter` isn't exhausted at the end of this iterator, so you could easily do it again and again until `my_iter` is exhausted.

Comment: Brad - thanks for this - I had to give it to DeepSpace as his was microseconds quicker and easy to add a step to it.... thanks Pal.

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answer have good and bad points. Wrapping `itertools.product` in your own generator is better that having to use a list comprehension every time but not raising StopIteration makes it run all the loop until `itertools.product` raises it.

```
def capped_product(l, limit):
    i = itertools.product(*l)
    for _ in range(limit):
        yield next(i)
    raise StopIteration

list(capped_product(z, 200))
```

Another approach would be having a generator that gives lists of the desired size incrementally. Example:

```
z = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]
n = 3

# First time you run it
first = [(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3)]
# Second time you run it
second = [(1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,2,1)]
# Third time you run it
third = [(1,2,2), (1,2,3), (1,2,4)]
# ...
```

Each time you get a list you get the following n combinations of list z. That could be done line:

```
def split_product(l, size):
    out = []
    for i in itertool.product(*l):
        out.append(i)
        if len(out) == size:
            yield out
            out = []

z = [[i for i in range(1, 36)] for _ in range(9)]
i = split_product(z, 200)
first = next(i)
second = next(i)
# ...
```